# I cannot get the AJAX code to accept the value from "onclick"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onclick

I apologize for the grammatical errors in my writing, I am not very good in language at all. Conceptually, I have some knowledge in software however, I have never written a line of code...

**MY SOFTWARE DESCRIPTION:**

I have thousands of songs/videos parked in my computer. Computer audio is connected to AV receiver and video is connected to a TV (for video). I'd like to write a piece code that I can play the music/video from the mobile devices, remotely. Here is my sequence for playing song:

1. use XAMMP, create the database holding the list of song/video names

   > completed and working
2. create html page, connect to the database, read, and display song names

   > completed and working
3. when click on the song name, a `SongID` is passed to Ajax code for posting `SongID` back to the server and then update the database with `PlayID`

   > I cannot get Ajax code working here!
4. other code will read `PlayID` from the database and play the song via VLC player

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id = "SongList">

<?php
    // Connect to mysql database
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "NangHa";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "ListSong";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // retrieve song list from mysql database table nangha_SongList
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nangha_SongList";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $song = (string)$row["SongID"] . " - " . $row["SongName"];
?>

    <!-- display list of songs with the onclick to call addSongFunction
         and pass the song id - $row["SongID"]
    -->
    <p id = "<?php echo $song;?>" onclick="addSongFunction(<?php echo $row["SongID"];?>)"><?php echo $song;?></p>
<?php
        }
    }
    // close the database connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>


<script>
    function addSongFunction(SongID){
        //convert song id to integer for testing
        var songID_STR = SongID.toString();
        var ID_SONG = SongID;

        // pass song id string to SongSearch div for testing
        document.getElementById("SongSearch").innerHTML = songID_STR;

        // display song id
        alert(+ ID_SONG);

        // SO FAR IS GOOD UP TO THIS POINT
        // JUST DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET AJAX WORKING

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                songID: ID_SONG
            },
            url: "UpdateKaraoke.php",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function(){
                alert(good);
                $(".ajaxTest").text("Trying to update ...");
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(+ data.a);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <p id = "<?php echo $song;?>" onclick='addSongFunction("<?php echo $row["SongID"];?>")'><?php echo $song;?></p>

Comment: And what exactly the problem is?

Comment: working at my end:- `<?php $row["SongID"] = 1;$song = "audio.mp3"?>

<p id = "<?php echo $song;?>" onclick='addSongFunction("<?php echo $row["SongID"];?>")'><?php echo $song;?></p>
<script src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addSongFunction(SongID){
       alert(SongID);
}
</script>`   (sample hard-coded example)

Comment: Anant, thank you.  I added <script src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> and it seems to be work.